In Jannah will everyone be white
Theres this hadith saying people in Jannah will have white skin
“The people of Paradise will enter Paradise without any hair on their body, beardless, with a fair complexion and curly hair, having kohl (collyrium) in their eyes, aged thirty-three years, and they will be in the form of Aadam, sixty cubits tall.”
but then theres also this hadith: On the night of my Ascent to Heaven, I saw Moosa (Moses), who was a tall, brown man...
Sahih al-Bukhari 3438
Are they contradictory? Also is it true all people in Jannah will be white? The arabic version of the hadith I showed first is:
حدثنا يزيد، أخبرنا حماد بن سلمة، عن علي بن زيد، عن سعيد بن المسيب، عن أبي هريرة، عن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم، قال: يدخل أهل الجنة الجنة جردًا، مردًا، بيضًا، جعادًا، مكحلين، أبناء ثلاث وثلاثين، على خلق آدم، ستون ذراعًا في عرض سبع أذرع.

Source of the first hadith? You have provided the Arabic in a format which makes it difficult to read.

@userNameAsString here is a link https://hadithanswers.com/another-hadith-on-the-description-of-the-inhabitants-of-jannah/
